# Sodium Deoxycholate titration assay

Tags: titration

Purchasing chemicals online often I see "Sodium Deoxycholate, ≥97% (**titration**)" offers. Is there any publicly available titration protocol I can use to confirm that statement in my very basic lab which does not have HPLC?

Comment: Probably not much of a help, but for what it's worth, [Merck's spec sheet](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/DataSheetPage.do?brandKey=SIGMA&symbol=30970) states "*TITRATION (NT) HCLO4 0.1M*".

Comment: @Alex For future reference: the addition *of context* will increase the value of your question for other readers of ChemSE.  In the present case, this could be / could have been *where*, or / and  *when* you see this.  For example «Purchasing chemicals, I often see their purity described in the pattern of e.g., "Sodium Deoxycholate, ≥97% (titration)."».  This may increase the likelihood for an answer, too.

Comment: Buttonwood, of course purchasing chemicals! What other kind of offers could I mean? Offers to spend a night on Tinder?
Buttonwood you are power-tripping

Comment: @Alex Buttonwood's suggestion is on-point and adds more clarity to your question. Please try to be more patient and don't bite the hand that feeds. Unfortunately, your question has been closed due to lack of clarity, but I think you can vote to re-open it after the edit—at this point I'm also interested in finding the answer:)

Comment: Alex I hope you find @Buttonwood and andselisk notes to be positive and helpful. For what it's worth, I too felt there wasn't enough context to expand on an answer.

Comment: Public (as in *published*, not as open access) are e.g., indirect assessments by titration calorimetry (e.g., [1995JPhysChem11742](https://doi.org/10.1021/j100030a019), or [2000Langmuir5267](https://doi.org/10.1021/la9912390)). Not a HPLC, but not this type of research is more likely seen in groups about enzyme binding, transition metal complexes, and physical chemistry.